# wordcloud2 integration for react

Tags: reactjs, word-cloud

I'm developing a react web application. I Want to use [this package](https://github.com/timdream/wordcloud2.js) for making a wordcloud. But it is not a react component. How can I use it in my application? Thanks All.

Comment: You might want to search for [react wordcloud](https://github.com/search?q=react+wordcloud) libraries on GitHub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite straight forward actually, please take a look at the sandbox I've setup to show the same - https://codesandbox.io/s/9435woonpy

#### Explanation:

1. Add `wordcloud` as a dependency to your project - `npm i --save wordcloud`

   > In case you're wondering how I got the name of the package, just take a look into the project's package.json - https://github.com/timdream/wordcloud2.js/blob/gh-pages/package.json and look at the `name` attribute; this is the name with which the project is available in [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordcloud) and you confirm this by also looking at the `author` on the npm page
2. `import 'wordcloud'` into the file in which you're going to use it
3. Have an empty canvas ('my-canvas') into which you will load the wordcloud into
4. On `componentDidMount`, invoke the `wordcloud` api to render the wordcloud into the DOM

Comment: This really helped me a lot. Thank you much. @Raghudevan

Comment: I'm glad I could help, please accept the answer and mark it useful if you can please! ^^  @sadjadghanbary

Comment: Is it possible to make the words clickable? To turn them into links to new pages?